# CSS3 Div Position

Tags: css, html, position

I have a loading circle that uses CSS3 Animations. Once the loading circle has finished animating, a empty div fades in. I am having problems placing the empty div ontop of another div. Any help is much appreciated.

[jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/kFPr6/4/)

Answer (score 4):

add `position:absolute;` and `top:0;` to box style

```
.box {
   background: #dedede;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   animation: in 3s forwards;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
}
```

have fun :)

Comment: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kFPr6/15/). Notice when you have other items above the element, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `z-index` to place elements in 'layers'.

```
z-index:1000;
```

Would make an element 1000 layers above 0 respectively.

Comment: I have tried that in another jsFiddle, But it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kFPr6/19/)   NEW jsFiddle includes elements above circles.

Create a new CSS rule for `.wrap` as follows:

```
.wrap{
  float: left;
}
```

*There is no need for you to use `z-index` property because you already have the DOM working with you, not against you.*